# How do I put several characters after the first letter and the last letter by use of Vim?

Tags: vim

How do I put several characters after the first letter and the last letter in the whole text by use of Vim?

E.g. I need to put `{{c1::` after the first letter and `}}` after the last letter. Also, I want to ignore two-letter words.

Comment: can you give a more clear example.  what do you want your text to look like before and after?

Comment: First letter of a paragraph? A word? The whole file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean in every word? Try this:

```
:%s/\<\(\w\)\(\w\w\+\)\>/\1{{c1::\2}}/g
```

That will replace every first character in a word with the first character followed by {{c1:: and add }} at the end of it. Words shorter than three characters are ignored.

If your words contain more than just [a-zA-Z0-9], then replace \w by a more appropriate character class.